# PowerShell - wait for Firefox to start, run imacro and wait for it to finish, close Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, powershell, imacros

I've tried simple like this:

```
'Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -Wait' 
Start-Sleep -s 20
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=MyJS.js -Wait'
```

But it does not finish the script before moving on.

And various tries using `-PassThru`, `-Wait`, `-Start` `-Sleep` and a key combo to start the jscript like:

```
'start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -PassThru; Start-Sleep -s 20;[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic");[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Login - Mozilla Firefox");[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms");[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%5")'
```

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is start Firefox, run an imacros jscript, wait for it to finish and then close Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're starting firefox first, and then running it again with the imacro specified.  So I'm skipping that in my solution.  I'd do something like this:

```
$cmdLine = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
$args = "imacros://run/?m=MyJS.js"
start-process $cmdLine $args
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
Get-Process | ? {$_.Name -like "firefox"} | %{$_.Close()}
```

Comment: I was attempting to follow iMacro's command line example in which they suggest having the FF process already started. Thank you!

Comment: The iMacros must have a couple seconds wait before launching (ff has to be active before iMacros knows MyJS.js exists).

Separating the 2 startups makes firefox open a 2nd window. Plugin 'TacMix+' did not help (ff ver 14.0.1).

'Site Launcher' plugin works via a hotkey with this code:

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic");[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Login - Mozilla Firefox");
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms");[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%5")

But does not 'wait'